# Adding new attributes using unetsack agents into Subnero research edition modems

Tags: unetstack

We are working on new routing protocol for underwater communication and want to test it on Subnero research edition modems.

1. If required attributes for routing algorithm not available in Subnero modem, can we introduce and deploy it in Subnero modems using unetstack agent?
2. Further can we define the behavior for new attribute?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "attributes". Could you clarify? Any Java/Groovy agent/script that you write and run on the simulator, can be copied to a modem running UnetStack and run on the modem. Subnero modems support this.

Comment: Attribute may be -  Number of packets queued in a intermediate hop, remaining energy etc.

Comment: Assuming you have these attributed advertised by your own agents, adding agents on modems that run UnetStack is no problem -- just copy to the `classes` folder and add it in the `scripts/setup.groovy` to load it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to develop your own agents and deploy them as part of Subnero modems, since the Subnero modems use UnetStack as their software framework.